# get object from a function reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Suppose we have made a javascript object class Client with a method init.
Then we do an instance of it named myClient.
myClient.init (without parenthesis) is the reference to that method.
Testing this reference how can I detect which is the object ? can I obtain the reference to the object or to the class ?

```
var foo = function(){
    alert(1);
};
```

foo (without parenthesis) is the reference to this anonymous function

We would like to determine the difference between those two references:
foo and myClient; we want to know if the reference belongs to the window object or is a method of an object and what is that object.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - functions in JavaScript don't really "belong" to anything, since the same function can be referenced in multiple places, and their context entirely depends on how you call them.  What's the underlying issue you're trying to solve here?

Comment: I'm not really following what your asking here. You talk about a Client and an init and then add a foo function. It's very confused

Comment: *"We would like to determine the difference between those two references: foo and myClient;"* o_O

Comment: What @JamesThorpe said with 1 note: "and their scope entirely depends on how you call them" --- the *scope* is determined during function definition and does not depend on how you call it.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, yes - scope wasn't the best choice of wording

Comment: @JamesThorpe you have 2.5 minutes to fix it! :-) I'd say just `s/scope/context/` would do that

Comment: @zerkms I'd flag it for moderator attention...

Comment: @zerkms thanks - much better word than the lengthy replacement I was coming up with :)